# make my richeditctrl

Tags: windows, mfc

I'd like to make my rich edit control unedittable but still able to receive and display data.

Thank you.

```
class myedit:public CRichEditCtrl
{
    public:
    private:
    protected:
       CRichEditCtrl m_editCtrl;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for [`CRichEditCtrl::SetReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dy5ey17.aspx).